# Add extensions to files in a file tree with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, regex

I'm trying to add extension to files extension-less in a tree.

The following command does not give satisfaction. How to achieve this ?

```
get-childitem * -recurse  -exclude *.h | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
    | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace "(.*)","$1.h"} -whatif
```

So I search for files, not directory, which are not `.*\.h`, and I rename them so they have a new extension.

Another replace command I tried is `{$_.name -replace '(.*)','$1.h'}` but this adds the extension twice. I only need the extension added once.

EDIT: the attempt excludes .h files and is sufficient, but for the question the more general "extension less" is more interesting and what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `-replace` function to get the new file name value. Use the `basename` property and the explicit `.h` extension for the value of the `-NewName` parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder\Path\*" -Recurse -Exclude *.h | 
Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | 
Rename-Item -NewName { "$($_.basename).h"} -WhatIf
```

### Supporting Resources

- > `Get-ChildItem` usually returns a `FileInfo` object. Those objects
  > contain a few useful properties—among them are...
  >
  > - the full path, file name, and extension (`FullName`),
  > - the path alone (`DirectoryName`),
  > - the file name (`Name`), and
  > - the file name without its extension (`BaseName`)
  >
  > [Source](https://4sysops.com/archives/split-path-get-childitem-splitting-file-names-in-powershell/)
- [Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1)
- [PowerShell Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

Comment: It does not work. `Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.` Also, why do I have the extension twice ? I used this `-replace` for new name many times without any problem, esp. with regexx expressions.

Comment: I corrected, and we both have the correct final result now. Still I find my command simpler and more clear, and provide a pointer to the zero match length kill problem.

Comment: @Soleil I find `-NewName { "$($_.basename).h"}` simple and clearer than `-newname {$_.name -replace '(.+)','$1.h'}` as and that's the only difference but mine does not require the additional replace function and uses existing property to get base name of each file. Both solutions use explicit append of `.h`.  It's beautiful when it works regardless!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any good reason to use:

- `Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer }`

when you have the [`-File`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) parameter in current versions of **PowerShell**.

And though this is a simple rename, I've gotten in the habit of using the [`-f` format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) operator:

- `-NewName { '{0}{1}' -f $_.BaseName , $NewExtension }`

( the extension could be hard-coded into the format string but this lends itself to being the basis for a reusable function )

So my take would be:

```
$MyFolder      = 'C:\Some\Folder\Path'
$NewExttension = '.h'

Get-ChildItem -Path $MyFolder -File -Recurse | ? Extension -eq '' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1}' -f $_.BaseName , $NewExtension } -Whatif
```

But as a one-off at the console could be shortened to:

```
gci $MyFolder -af -s | ? Extension -eq '' | ren -new {"$($_.BaseName)$NewExtension"}
```

Comment: Why using `| ? Extension -eq ''` in place of `-exclude *.h` ?

Comment: @ITThugNinja I apologize, I actually have either .h either extensionless files, and I confused myself. So the right thing is "extensionless". My attempt (excluding the .h) in the OP was wrong and misleading. I apologize again.

Answer (score 0):

With minimum changes, the problem was the regex expression, where * matches 0 (and [does not kill zero length match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351217/why-do-some-regex-engines-match-twice-in-a-single-input-string#52352744)), and + at least one; subsequently, the following command works as expected (if one has only .h and extensionless files):

```
get-childitem * -recurse  -exclude *.h | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
    | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace '(.+)','$1.h'} -whatif
```